# Do mustache.js templates modulas operator?

Tags: mustache

Is there a modulas operator (`%`) for mustache templates?

The modulas operator helps to determine if the current record being processed is even or odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Mustache templates generally do not have any operator of any kind, nor they have any syntax for number literals: `{{ index % 2 }}` fails for both the `%` operator, and the `2` literal. The only expressions allowed in a Mustache tag are identifiers such as `{{ foo }}` and `{{ foo.bar }}`.

Now, you can look after [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com) templates. They are compatible with Mustache, and are much more versatile and flexible. Finding odd and even indexes is quite possible with Handlebars. You won't have any % operator, but you'll have rich "helpers" that will allow you to write something similar to `{{# even @index }}...{{ else }}...{{/ even }}`